# Word for the object of adoration

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What would be a word for the object of adoration? E.g., a public speaker, a movie actor or a character in a novel.

In short, if I am a fan of X, then X is my *_*_.

Please note that the adoration here is not excessive, and therefore I am looking for a word weaker than '*idol*'.

Comment: You might consider that most people use the term *idol* in just the way you intend (without the excess).  But you might go with **one of my favorite** ***<fitting characterization of X>***

Comment: @Jim Hmm. I was trying to avoid it, but I guess I have to go for it. There should really be more degrees of strength here. New words in English for this purpose will help.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, by the way.

Comment: Hang around for a couple of hours, someone might come up with a better suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why the lexicon has not considered this but the natural choice should have been,

*admiree*

[Lamers, M.](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=Eoe8RhLy3IUC&pg=PA123&dq=%22admiree%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SI21Uv-BFIGMrQfIsYD4Bg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22admiree%22&f=false):

> The verb *admire* needs two arguments, the admirer (someone doing the admiring), and the **admiree** (the entity being admired).

[Kecskes, I.](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=K9jUJxY6m0EC&pg=PA167&dq=%22admiree%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SI21Uv-BFIGMrQfIsYD4Bg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22admiree%22&f=false)

> A speaker may choose which aspects of someone they admire to mimic in speaking to other people, in part from an audience design consideration (e.g., don't mimic an **admiree** to an addressee who knows both you and the **admiree**; they'll likely notice your mimicry and possibly call you on it).

[Maienborn, C.](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=-026poXzQDMC&pg=PA416&dq=%22admiree%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SI21Uv-BFIGMrQfIsYD4Bg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22admiree%22&f=false)

> … the contrast between *admiration of him* (*admirer* and ***admiree*** must be distinct) and *admiration of himself* (*admirer* and ***admiree*** must be identical) suggests that even arguments that are not necessarily syntatically realized play a crucial role in binding.

Answer (score 1):

Really the word fan is a contraction of the word 'fanatic' according to the Oxford English Dictionary

Merriam-Webster defines 'fan' as:

> an enthusiastic devotee (as of a sport or a performing art) usually as a spectator
>   or an ardent admirer or enthusiast (as of a celebrity or a pursuit)

So you could really say 'x is my admired/devoted' but that just sounds awkward. Maybe just use the idiom 'apple of my eye'?

Comment: You do get what I am trying to get at. That awkwardness is exactly what I am trying to avoid. Secondly, "Apple of my eye" gives a bit of a personal touch don't you think? Like, my son or my lover would be the apple of my eye, and certainly not, say, a movie actor.

Comment: Yeah I completely agree, it seems as though you can only go too far with this one: idol, 'apple of my eye', hero, icon.
How much of a fan are you? That's the real question :P

Comment: 'My number one' (is an open compound a 'word'?)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few expressions which you could use depending on your level of devotion and admiration.

X is my

- mentor
- inspiration
- hero
- icon
- favourite actor/musician etc.

Comment: Not exactly my "mentor", "inspiration", as I am not in the same field. Calling him favorite seems a bit weak in my opinion. I can get behind "hero" or "icon", though not quite what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Then  you'll probably have to rephrase your sentence to: He's someone whom I admire greatly (or) respect.

Answer (score 0):

Why not *beloved*? It seems to fit the bill in most respects.

*Idol* has a connotation of someone people want to be like, whereas *beloved* clearly shows adoration (deep love & respect) without a desire to emulate.

Common usage for the noun form of *beloved* does lean towards a more romantic interest, but its adjective form is a popular choice for describing public figures, institutions, foods, etc.

I'm of the opinion that it'd be a good existing word to stretch the meaning of.

Comment: This would be improved with a dictionary reference for the selected word.

Comment: Asking the OP "why not" is putting the cart before the horse. Your answer should explain *why* your suggestion is suitable.